# How do I submit my phone gap application on the blackberry store?

Tags: android, blackberry, cordova

I want to submit my phone gap application on the Blackberry store. I have a WWW folder which contains all the files. The app has already been submitted on the Android and Apple.

How do I submit my phone gap application on the blackberry store?

Comment: That folder only contains the web files. You need to compile the project and once you get the resulting .cod or .bar files, you need to sign them, and then we can start talking about submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

It's amazing what a simple Google Search can do.  I would suggest building the app into whatever package BlackBerry uses.  Look at the PhoneGap Documentation to see how to do that.  Or use PhoneGap Build and it builds your app into all package types for all devices.  Then just follow the links to ["Submit Your App or Theme"](http://developer.blackberry.com/blackberryworld/)